# v-model property doesn't show inside tinymce

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

I have v-model property, my problem is property doesn't show in tinymce even I can see it in inspect element.

```
<label>Nama : @{{ adDetailOrder.gajah }}</label>
<input type="text" name="nama" v-model="adDetailOrder.gajah" style="margin-bottom:0px" class="form-control" v-validate.initial="'required|alpha_spaces'" placeholder="Full Name">

<label>@{{ adDetailOrder.gajah }} ... ...</label>
<textarea id="description" class="form-control" rows="3" name="description">... @{{ adDetailOrder.gajah }} ...
</textarea>
```

Here is my vue

```
data: {
            ...

            adDetailOrder: {

                gajah: '',
            }
```

Here is picture

[image: tinymce doesn't show v-model]

this is someone is adDetailOrder.gajah

Where I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? Could you add answer with code used?